# Ignore StyleCop rule in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, stylecop, editorconfig

I do my development in Visual Studio Code and have recently started using StyleCop to improve my coding style in C#.

In my `.csproj` file, I added a `PackageReference` to `StyleCop.Analyzers` and can now see several warnings in the Problems window. However, I do not want to follow one of the suggestions, SA1633, "The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file". Following suggestions, I created a `.editorconfig` file at the root of my solution (one directory above my project) and added the lines

```ini
# Don't want to require file header
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1633.severity = none
```

However the warning still shows up both in the Problems window and when I build the solution with `dotnet build`. All the discussion I have found that talks about this is for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

What is the proper way, in Visual Studio Code, to change the severity of a StyleCop rule?

Comment: Did you qualify the rules with `[*]` or `[*.cs]`? Also try some of the alternatives [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files).

Comment: @NPras Thank you. That got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NPras got me pointed in the right direction. There were two different issues.

1. I had let an extension create a default `.editorconfig` file for me. When I added my rules to the end, I did not take into account the qualifiers and so they inherited the qualifiers of the last entry which was not what I needed. I added the qualifier of `[*.cs]` before my rules and `dotnet build` began respecting the rules.
2. The *Problems* window in Visual Studio does not pick up on a reduction of severity upon saving an `.editorconfig` file (though it apparently does pick up changing the severity from `none` to `warn`). The warnings were still being shown in the window. Restarting Visual Studio Code or even just reloading the window (command `Developer: Reload Window`) fixed this synchronization/caching (?) issue. It is not a quick process, but altering the severity of these checks should not be a frequent occurrence and so that workaround is acceptable to me.